# The using of Borsuk-Ulam theorem

Tags: general-topology

Let a circle $k:(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=r^2$, $p,q\in\mathbb{R},\thinspace r>0 $  and a point $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be given. Prove that there exists a square $[x_0-a,x_0+a]\times[y_0-a,y_0+a],\thinspace a>0$ whose boundary contains at least one pair of diametrically opposed points from the circle $k$.

I suppose that I can use Borsuk-Ulam theorem, but I don't know how to find the continuous function from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, and later from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As a tiny beginning one may assume that $p=q=0$ and $r=1$, for what it's worth.

Comment: Border = boundary?

Comment: Yes, it's boundary.

Answer (score 3):

As in the comments, without loss of generality the circle is $S^1$, write $p = (x_0,y_0)$.

Consider the taxicab norm $\|\cdot \|_1$ on the plane and $d$ the induced distance. Then $$[x_0-a,x_0+a] \times [y_0-a,y_0+a] = B_a^d(p),$$
a point $q$ is in that square precisely if $d(p,q) \leq a$ and it lies in the boundary iff $d(p,q) = a$.

Define $d(-,p) \colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ to be the taxicab distance to $p$. This is $\|\cdot\|_1$-continuous by its very definition, but by the equivalence of norms in $\Bbb R^2$ it is also continuous for the usual distance on the plane.

Now consider the restriction $\delta \colon S^1 \to \Bbb R$. By Borsuk-Ulam, there exists a point $x \in S^1$ such that $\delta(x) = \delta(-x) = a$. Note that $a \geq 0$ because $\delta \geq 0$, but moreover $a > 0$ or otherwise we would have $x = p = -x$ which is absurd, as $x \in S^1$.

By a previous remark, this means that $x,-x \in \partial B_a^d(p)$, as desired.

Comment: Very nice proof!